# how to define the kendo grid filterable operators but keep using its default string

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the following situation, a kendo grid and I want to select which filter operators, this works fine:

```
var filters_op = {
  operators: {
    string: {
      eq: "Is equal to",
      neq: "Is not equal to",
      contains: "Contains"
    }
  }
}

element.kendoGrid({
  dataSource: dataSource,
  filterable: filters_op,
  columns: ...
  ...
});
```

However my application is multi-language, and previous I had the property `filterable: true` (or false) and the vendor [kendo global](https://github.com/loudenvier/kendo-global.git) do the work to translate and brings its own filterable operators.

On the other hand, the default operators from Kendo Global contains some filters like "starts with", "Is after", "Is after or equal to"... which my application doesn't support yet, and when I override them, I lose the translation support from K.Global

Is it possible to have both, select which I want and the translate from K.Glbl together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't choose which one of the [kendo global](https://github.com/loudenvier/kendo-global) operators will be translated on the `filterable` parameter of your [kendoGrid](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/overview) function. Kendo does not allow that, yet.

However, you can translate the operators by yourself (or by a third-party library) and provide them on the `filters_op`. That will override the kendo default `filters` and also translate them.

I recommend you to use the `I18n.t` translate method of the [i18n](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) to do that. Your code will look like this, for example:

```js
var filtersOp = {
  operators: {
    string: {
      eq: I18n.t('kendo.grid.filterable.operators.string.eq'),
      neq: I18n.t('kendo.grid.filterable.operators.string.neq'),
      contains: I18n.t('kendo.grid.filterable.operators.string.contains')
    },
    date: {
      eq: I18n.t('kendo.grid.filterable.operators.date.eq'),
      neq: I18n.t('kendo.grid.filterable.operators.date.neq')
    },
    enums: {
      eq: I18n.t('kendo.grid.filterable.operators.enums.eq'),
      neq: I18n.t('kendo.grid.filterable.operators.enums.neq')
    }
  }
}

...

element.kendoGrid({
   ...
   filterable: filtersOp,
   columns: ...
   ...
})
```

As you can see, the `I18n` library will handle this translation procedure.